# How to crawl data from a website and append it into an excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, web, web-crawler

I need to do some real estate market research and for that I need the prices and other values of new homes.

So my idea was to go to the website where I get the information. Go to the main search page and scrape all the RealEstateIDs that would take me directly to the individual pages for each house where I can extract the information I need.
I have two problems: 
First, the website has around 60 IDs, but I only get about 20 IDs.
Second, the format in the Excel spreadsheet puts the column headers back above each entry, and each entry only in one cell instead of in different columns.

If someone could explain to me how I can solve these problems and tell me what I did wrong, I would be very happy to hear that

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import datetime as dt 
import os
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import re
import time
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv

res = requests.get('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-T/Wohnung-Kauf/Nordrhein-Westfalen/Duesseldorf/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/true?enteredFrom=result_list') #This is the main search site where I get the IDs
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r'resultListModel:(.*)')
data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
script = r.findall(data)[0].rstrip(',')
results = json.loads(script)
ids = [item['@id'] for item in results['searchResponseModel']['resultlist.resultlist']['resultlistEntries'][0]['resultlistEntry']] #This should get me the IDs and put it into a list so i can use it later
print(ids) #My test that I get all the IDs and not just a few

data = json.dumps(ids)
houseinfo = {} 

csvData = [['id','purchasePrice','Spacesize','District','Flattyp','Rooms']] #Dataformat for the Excel-Spreadsheet colums later

def get_house_info (House):                                                 #this is the function that inserts the IDs from the List into the URLs and than scraps the Values that I need into a new list
    for id in ids:
        try:
            sourceCode = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/' + str(id)).read()
            purchasePrice = str(sourceCode).split('"purchasePrice":')[1].split(',"geoCode"')[0]
            Spacesize = str(sourceCode).split('"area":')[1].split('},"details"')[0]
            District = str(sourceCode).split('"quarter":')[1].split('},')[0]
            Flattyp = str(sourceCode).split('"is24qa-typ grid-item three-fifths">')[1].split('</dd> </dl> <dl class')[0]
            Rooms = str(sourceCode).split('is24qa-zimmer grid-item three-fifths"> ')[1].split(' </dd> </dl> <dl class=')[0]

            with open('foo.csv', 'a') as csvfile:                           #appends the values to the file
                cols = ['id', 'price', 'size', 'district', 'flattyp', 'rooms']
                dict_result = {'id': id, 'price': purchasePrice, 'size': Spacesize, 'district': District, 'flattyp': Flattyp, 'rooms': Rooms}
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=cols)
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerow(dict_result)

            csvfile.close()



        except Exception as e:

            print("failed in the main loop", str(e))

get_house_info(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant say exact about your code, but following links might be helpful to you :
1."Web scraping in Python" by Data School YouTube Channel 4 part videos.